# TSQL Insert with selection statement if not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am inserting multiple records into a table from a select statement. The select statement can contain multiple records as its an XML string.

```
INSERT INTO empowermentEntries (sessionID, submissionID, whoAdded, [timestamp])
    SELECT @sessionID,
           ParamValues.x1.value('theID[1]', 'INT'),
           @empID,
           GETDATE()
    FROM   @entries.nodes('/submission/submissionID') AS ParamValues(x1);
```

However, I want to prevent records from being added to this table if they already exist.

Is it possible to combine this with an `IF NOT EXISTS` ?

Comment: What does "they already exist" mean ? Shall duplicates be in the xml, or xml does always have distinct values (but they may already be existing values in db) ?

Comment: XML could contain a value that already exists in the table. I don't want there to be a duplicate value

Comment: So I think you can perfectly do a not exists on empowermentEntries. Adding something like `where not exists (select null from empowermentEntries where ParamValues.x1.something = anotherfield)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the info - this worked.

```
INSERT INTO empowermentEntries (sessionID, submissionID, whoAdded, [timestamp])
    SELECT @sessionID,
           ParamValues.x1.value('theID[1]', 'INT'),
           @empID,
           GETDATE()
    FROM   @entries.nodes('/submission/submissionID') AS ParamValues(x1)
    WHERE not exists(SELECT 
                    sessionID, submissionID
                    FROM empowermentEntries
                    WHERE sessionID = @sessionID AND submissionID = ParamValues.x1.value('theID[1]', 'INT'));
```